# How to increase reach of mouse pointer in one go?

Tags: mouse, touchpad

The mouse pointer only moves a few centimetres in one stretch on touchpad. I want it to travel the entire screen in one go. How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Open `System Settings` > `Mouse & Touchpad` and under the `Touchpad` section adjust `Pointer Speed`'s level